# Is every hyperplane distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by a nowhere vanishing one form?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

From wikipedia: Contact geometry is the study of a geometric structure on smooth manifolds given by a hyperplane distribution in the tangent bundle satisfying a condition called 'complete non-integrability'. Equivalently, such a distribution may be given (at least locally) as the kernel of a differential one-form, and the non-integrability condition translates into a maximal non-degeneracy condition on the form

So I am not an expert in contact geometry and I was hoping, until recently, that I could just think of these things as their corressponding one-forms. However, 
after thinking for about five mintues on a compact simply connected manifold, at least, it is clear that such one-form cannot exist globally, so the more "typical" contact structure is defined by a one-form only locally. Are there any conditions saying it CAN be defined globally? Intuitively, I feel like if the manifold is contractible, at least, such a one-form should be defined globally. Would this be correct, for instance?

Comment: Locally, you can do this with a unit length 1-form. Any two such agree up to sign, a cocycle on Euclidean space valued in -1,1. The cohomology class of the cocycle gets in the way if it doesn't vanish, but on Euclidean space clearly it does: a coboundary, so you can patch it up by choosing signs again to get agreement.

Comment: To add to Ben's comment, that cohomology class has a name: $w_1(TM/\xi) \in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\xi$ is a hyperplane distribution (not even necessarily contact) on $M$. In fact, the condition $w_1(TM/\xi) = 0$ is equivalent to having a globally defined 1-form for $\xi$. Hence, whatever simply connected counterexample you were thinking of cannot exist.

Comment: Kevin is totally right.  I just want to add the name of this class $w_1$.  It is called "first Stiefel-Whitney class" (so that you can more easily look it up, see eg Milnor-Stasheff).